# JQuery UI Autocomplete not triggering on typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JQuery UI Autocomplete field that accesses a Ruby function behind the scenes. Typing into the box doesn't trigger the call to the server to load the options. Pressing the Down key will do so however and it works fine after that. Any ideas why this might be?

HTML

```
<div id="subject_select_dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 141px; " scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
   <input id="subject_select" name="subject" size="70" type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
   <button id="subject_select_clear" name="button" type="clear">Clear</button>
   ...
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#subject_select").autocomplete({
  source: "/users/autocomplete", 
  minLength: 2,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#subject_select" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#subject_select").val( ui.item.label )
    $("#subject_select_results").html( ui.item.label )
    $("#subject_select_id").val( ui.item.value )
    return false;
  }
});
```

Ruby

```
def autocomplete
  render :json => UserProfile.list_by_name(params[:term]).to_json
end
```

EDIT:

Examining the generated HTML, it's flagging my field as `Autocomplete="off"`. When I manually change that value in my debugger, the correct behavior appears. Why would it be flagging it with such an attribute and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does Firebug / other debugging tools show any requests being fired for typing? Is there any other `keypress/keyup/keydown` handlers on that field that might be stopping this autocomplete from working?

Comment: As a sanity check, you are typing at least 2 characters?

Comment: Please fix your HTML so that it's what's actually generated by your back-end script.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Yup.

@Madbreaks That led me more directly to the real problem! Apparently it has the `Autocomplete="off"` attribute. Changing it to `"on"` gives me the correct behavior. Now I guess I need to figure out why it's setting Autocomplete off. Will edit in the new info.

Comment: Now it's working correctly out of the box, even though I haven't changed anything. :\ Hate bugs like these because they can come back to bite me.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with an MVC 4 app.  I have a table with dynamically added rows, each with a textbox that I want the autocomplete on.  For some reason, the autocomplete="off" attribute is added even though I specify it NOWHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Autocomplete` attribute for the input field to which JQuery UI Autocomplete is applied. Ensure that it is set to `"on"` and not `"off"`.

--

I am answering this question as Community using comments on the question, for the benefit of future readers.